# JSON, php убрать из массива одинаковые элементы

Tags: php, ajax, json

подскажите пожалуйста как удалить или скомпоновать одинаковые данные из массива JSON
Просто вывести могу, дублируются строчки с routID возможно ли их скомпоновать

```
{"result":[{"parkNumber":"1308",**"routeId":"1103"**,"arrivingTime":"2019-02-25 14:29:38","wheelchair":true,"orderNumber":9},{"parkNumber":"1686","routeId":"5581","arrivingTime":"2019-02-25 14:31:57","wheelchair":false,"orderNumber":5},{"parkNumber":"1949",**"routeId":"1103"**,"arrivingTime":"2019-02-25 14:40:22","wheelchair":false,"orderNumber":11},{"parkNumber":"1222","routeId":"1088","arrivingTime":"2019-02-25 14:43:50","wheelchair":true,"orderNumber":8},{"parkNumber":"1322","routeId":"1091","arrivingTime":"2019-02-25 14:45:37","wheelchair":true,"orderNumber":10}],"success":true}
```

Просто получаю данные

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://загрузка json файла');
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj->result as $statement){
echo $statement->routeId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://загрузка json файла');
$used_route_ids = [];
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj->result as $statement){
    if(in_array($statement->routeId, $used_route_ids)) continue;
    $used_route_ids[] = $statement->routeId;
    echo $statement->routeId;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, а не подскажите, возможно ли дубликаты сгруппировать?

Comment: по каким критериям ? покажите что Вы хотите получить в результате

Comment: routeId повторяются в списке, но разное время прибытия транспортного средства, вот возможно ли сгруппировать одинаковые номера routeId к примеру выстроить их один за другим